# Limits of XSLT Grouping?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I need to change the snippet below into a hierarchical structure by grouping related elements under new group element. XSLT sounds like the appropriate technology to use here but I don't know enough about it to assess if it's capable of what I need. An example grouping criteria is "1 'd' node followed by some number of '3' nodes, followed by 1 'f' node". I have to perform this task for several separate criteria, so I'd like to know if queries of that nature are possible in XSLT or if I would be better served just giving up and processing the DOM procedurally. I'm completely open to other strategies, as well. For a specific example, I need to convert this-

```
<root>
    <a>foo</a>
    <b>bar</b>
    <c>baz</c>
    <d>location</d>
    <e>3.14</e>
    <e>6.02</e>
    <e>1.23</e>
    <f>2015</f>
    <d>location</d>
    <e>3.14</e>
    <e>6.02</e>
    <f>2015</f>
</root>
```

Into this-

```
<root>
    <a>foo</a>
    <b>bar</b>
    <c>baz</c>
    <sample>
        <d>location</d>
        <e>3.14</e>
        <e>6.02</e>
        <e>1.23</e>
        <f>2015</f>
    </sample>
    <sample>
        <d>location</d>
        <e>3.14</e>
        <e>6.02</e>
        <f>2015</f>
    </sample>
</root>
```

Comment: Can the input XML have more than 3(or less, or none) `e` elements after `d`? Same question for the `f` elements, can there be more or none. How would you like to handle it? And please mention the version of XSLT you are using? 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Any solution to a grouping problem is going to depend on whether you use 1.0 or 2.0. You need to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is that you want to group the elements, starting-with `d`, you can use the following approach. 
**XSLT-1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- key to select following (e|f) elements using the first preceding d's id -->
    <xsl:key name="following" match="e | f" use="generate-id(preceding::d[1])"/>

    <!-- identity transform template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to group d and its following (e|f) elements under sample element-->
    <xsl:template match="d">
        <sample>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current() | key('following', generate-id())"/>
        </sample>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to do nothing for e|f elements -->
    <xsl:template match="e|f"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And, of course, XSLT isn't limited to such simple grouping.

Comment: Perfect! As a follow-up question- If I need to 'group the groups' at a higher level, can I add other templates later in the stylesheet or does than need to be done in another stylesheet altogether?

Comment: @JSacksteder I'm glad that the code worked for you. It depends on what transformation is desired. At a higher level, grouping can be done in a single stylesheet too. Either in one phase of transformation or in multiple phases. By multiple phases, I mean, have a variable to store the current transformation and again run more templates on the variable using exslt:node-set(). It becomes more easier if you are using XSLT-2.0. You may edit the current question or ask a new question.

Comment: This assumes that "e" elements follow immediately a "d" element. Will produce incorrect results if this assumption isn't true.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I thought the OP had made a mistake in this statement _followed by some number of '3' nodes_, and actually meant `e` nodes.

Comment: @JSacksteder could you please update your question if my assumption is right.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - That understanding is safe; Ordering is guaranteed.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my take on an approach, given that I normally work in an XSLT 1.0 environment.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <!-- any nodes that I don't address specifically, I copy -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- from the root, deal with a, b, c, d nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="a|b|c|d"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- the d node is the fun one -->
    <xsl:template match="d">
        <!-- add the wrapper -->
        <sample>
            <!-- first, copy the d node -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <!--
            process any following sibling e nodes if that
            e node's immediately preceding d sibling is the
            "current" node - i.e. the d node that got us here

            We use the fact that in XSLT 1.0, a union of nodes
            will never contain duplicates, so if the count is
            one, that means the two parts of the union are the
            same node
            -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::e
                [count(current() | preceding-sibling::d[1]) = 1]"/>
            <!-- same logic for f nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::f
                [count(current() | preceding-sibling::d[1]) = 1]"/>
        </sample>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, whether this convinces you that XSLT is the right tool or sends you screaming in horror depends on your personality, I suppose.